# Use FB Send button

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

I am new to FB integration. I want to use FB send button, to send invites to my facebook friends.

Below is the code I used.

```
<div>
 <span> To choose friends from your facebook list , click here :    </span >
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
         }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

 <div class="fb-send" data-href="http://61.12.14.179/fb_test.html"></div>

 </div>
```

I get a fb send button. But when I click on the fb send button, select my friends to send invites, it displays as *"We encountered the following error while sending your message"* and no error message is displayed.

Message is also not sent.
Any help?

Answer (score -1):

Try Something like:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : 'your_app_id',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
  });
</script>

<fb:like href="your_url" send="true" width="450" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>
```

This will show the send button that works.

Comment: i still have same error :(.. please check the below url for screenshot what I have... http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/826/fberror.png/

Comment: In the data-ref parameter, should I give domainname or will the IP address work ?

Comment: that should work with IP address as well, but since it didnt work for you can you try replacing it with domain name..?